# Writing converse of a statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I read the following statement

> For any nonzero integers $a$ and $b$ there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=as+bt$.

and then tried to think about its converse, which I thought is

> For any two nonzero integers $a$ and $b$ if there exists integers $s$ and $t$ such that $as+bt=d$ then $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

Is the converse right?

Comment: The assumption is that "$a$ and $b$ are integers." There is no really good converse, since if $a$ or $b$ is not an integer, $\gcd(a,b)$ doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: With $a=1,b=1$ we can choose $(s,t)=(5,5)$, in which case $as+bt=5$.  Does that mean that $5=\gcd(1,1)$?

Comment: @lulu Don't you mean $as+bt=10$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath  I do indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The **original statement** “for all nonzero integers $a$ and $b,$ there exist integers $s$ and
  $t$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=as+bt$” can be translated as $$\forall\,
     a,b\bigg(a,b\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\implies\exists\, s,t\in\mathbb
     Z \;\gcd(a,b)=as+bt\bigg).\tag1$$
- Therefore, its **converse** is $$\forall\, a,b\bigg(\exists\,
     s,t\in\mathbb Z \;\bigg[\gcd(a,b)=as+bt\bigg]\implies a,b\in\mathbb
     Z\setminus\{0\}\bigg),\tag2$$ which translate to natural language as “for
  all variables $a$ and $b,$ if there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such
  that $\gcd(a,b)=as+bt,$ then $a$ and $b$ are nonzero integers.”

On the other hand, your suggestion “for all nonzero integers $a$ and $b,$ if there exists integers $s$ and $t$ such that $as+bt=d,$ then $d=\gcd(a,b)$” translates as $$\forall \,d\;\;\forall\, a,b\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\} \bigg(\exists\, s,t\in\mathbb Z \:\:\bigg[d=as+bt\bigg]\implies d=\gcd(a,b)\bigg),\tag3$$ which is not actually the converse of the original statement.

P.S. None of this is discussing validity or actual truth—just about translation between first-order logic and natural language.

P.P.S. Statements $(1),(2),(3)$ are logically equivalent to
$$\forall\,
   a,b\;\:\exists\, s,t\bigg(s,t\in\mathbb
   Z \:\text{ and } \bigg[a,b\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\implies\gcd(a,b)=as+bt\bigg]\bigg),\tag4$$
$$\forall\, a,b\;\;\forall\,
   s,t \bigg(\bigg[s,t\in\mathbb Z \:\text{ and } \gcd(a,b)=as+bt\bigg]\implies a,b\in\mathbb
   Z\setminus\{0\}\bigg),\tag5$$
$$\forall \,d\;\;\forall\, a,b \;\;\forall\, s,t \bigg(\bigg[a,b\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\} \:\text{ and }\: s,t\in\mathbb Z \:\text{ and }\: d=as+bt\bigg]$$$$\implies d=\gcd(a,b)\bigg),\tag6$$ respectively.